# Convert $x/y \cdot \frac{1-\delta_1-\delta_3}{(1-\delta_2)}$ to $x/y \cdot (1-\delta)$ using calculus

Tags: calculus, infinitesimals, floating-point, rounding-error

Want expression in the form $x/y \cdot (1-\delta)$

- $\delta_3 \delta_1$ and anything $\delta^2$ can be excluded since they are too small
- $=x/y \cdot \frac{(1-\delta_1)}{(1-\delta_2)}(1-\delta_3)\\=x/y \cdot \frac{(\delta_3 \delta_1 - \delta_1 - \delta_3 + 1)}{(1-\delta_2)}\\\approx x/y \cdot \frac{1-\delta_1-\delta_3}{(1-\delta_2)}$

As you can see its not in the correct form I'm not sure how to simplify the denominator in this case.

Here is an example with multiplication/addition from my textbook
[image]

Comment: $(1-\delta_1)^{-1}=1+\delta_1+....$(Binomial expansion)

Comment: So using that the first equation can be made to $$\approx x/y (1-\delta_1)(1-\delta_3)(1+\delta_2)$$

Comment: $$ = x/y(-\delta_2 \delta_1 + \delta_2 \delta_3 \delta_1 + \delta_3 \delta_1 - \delta_1 + \delta_2 - \delta_2 \delta_3 - \delta_3 + 1)$$ $$\approx x/y (1 - \delta_1 + \delta_2 - \delta_3)$$  $\delta = \delta_1 - \delta_2 + \delta_3$. I think that works

Comment: Yes, multiply, and keep the linear terms.

Comment: Think so too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $\max_i(|\delta_i|)\leqslant\epsilon$:
$$\frac{1-\delta_1-\delta_3}{1-\delta_2} \leqslant 1-\delta \iff 1-\delta_1-\delta_3 \leqslant (1-\delta_2)(1-\delta) = 1-\delta_2-\delta+\delta_2\delta \iff$$
$$\iff \delta \leqslant \delta_1-\delta_2+\delta_3 \iff |\delta| \leqslant |\delta_1-\delta_2+\delta_3| \leqslant |\delta_1|+|\delta_2|+|\delta_3| \leqslant 3\epsilon$$
So if you set $|\delta| \leqslant 3\epsilon$, you get:
$$\frac{x}{y} . \frac{1-\delta_1-\delta_3}{1-\delta_2} \leqslant x/y.(1-\delta)$$

Comment: its floating point epsilon I'm not too sure about it though

Comment: OK, I edit my answer.